# Configuración Tor servidor

Tags: configuration

No entiendo bien el significado de las 3 últimas lineas de el registro de Tor.
Es correcta la configuración de mi archivo Torrc?

```
Jul 23 21:01:19.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.7.6 (git-605ae665009853bd) opening new log file.
Jul 24 01:44:03.000 [notice] Interrupt: we have stopped accepting new connections, and will shut down in 30 seconds. Interrupt again to exit now.
Jul 24 01:44:33.000 [notice] Clean shutdown finished. Exiting.
Jul 24 21:18:16.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.7.6 (git-605ae665009853bd) opening log file.
Jul 24 21:18:16.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Jul 24 21:18:16.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Jul 24 21:18:16.000 [notice] Configured to measure statistics. Look for the *-stats files that will first be written to the data directory in 24 hours from now.
Jul 24 21:18:16.000 [warn] Unable to parse '/etc/resolv.conf', or no nameservers in '/etc/resolv.conf' (6)
Jul 24 21:18:16.000 [warn] Couldn't set up any working nameservers. Network not up yet?  Will try again soon.
Jul 24 21:18:17.000 [notice] Your Tor server's identity key fingerprint is 'delfininterior DDA6FC85FEC510B479382CC3A0F2B543727202CA'
Jul 24 21:18:17.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Jul 24 21:18:53.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Jul 24 21:18:54.000 [notice] Guessed our IP address as 47.61.152.79 (source: 86.59.21.38).
Jul 24 21:18:56.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
Jul 24 21:18:56.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Jul 24 21:18:56.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Jul 24 21:18:56.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
Jul 24 21:18:56.000 [notice] Now checking whether ORPort 47.61.152.79:9001 and DirPort 47.61.152.79:9030 are reachable... (this may take up to 20 minutes -- look for log messages indicating success)
Jul 24 21:18:59.000 [notice] Self-testing indicates your DirPort is reachable from the outside. Excellent.
Jul 24 21:19:00.000 [notice] Self-testing indicates your ORPort is reachable from the outside. Excellent. Publishing server descriptor.
Jul 24 21:19:02.000 [notice] Performing bandwidth self-test...done.
Jul 24 21:31:55.000 [notice] Received reload signal (hup). Reloading config and resetting internal state.
Jul 24 21:31:55.000 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Jul 24 21:31:55.000 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions should be posted in English.

Comment: Lo siento, no entiendo Ingles, me arreglo con traductores. Gracias por su colaboración.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last 3 lines mean that Tor has received a signal from the kernel, that signal tells it to reload it's configuration, which is has done.

It has found no problems with the configuration and should function normally.

Sometimes this can happen as a result of services like `logrotate`.